# 400 Bad Request in Response

Tags: salesforce1-app, integration, oauth2, rest, angular

I have been using working on an Applicaion in angularjs, and While getting response of 2nd request for the token, I am getting following an error.

Illegal Request
You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request.

and it shows 400 Bad Request

My code is as below.

```
var url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
            params = {
                code:'dfdfsdsd',
                grant_type:'authorization_code',
                client_id:'23232',
                client_secret:'weewew',
                redirect_uri: redirectURL
            };
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: params,
        transformRequest: function(data){
            var fd = new FormData();
            for ( i in data){
                if(data.hasOwnProperty(i))
                    fd.append(i, data[i]);
            }
            return fd;
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data','Accept': "*/*"}
```

My request payload is

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybowCNKs3dC85tBTV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code"

dfdfsdsd
------WebKitFormBoundarybowCNKs3dC85tBTV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

authorizatidon_code
------WebKitFormBoundarybowCNKs3dC85tBTV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

2323zK
------WebKitFormBoundarybowCNKs3dC85tBTV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_secret"

232
------WebKitFormBoundarybowCNKs3dC85tBTV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="redirect_uri"

http://redirect url
------WebKitFormBoundarybowCNKs3dC85tBTV--
```

What should be the problem ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Your payload example has the "redirect_uri" set to `http://redirect url` which is not a valid URL. Are you sure you are sending a valid URL for the OAUTH logic to call back to?

Comment: I am sending redirect_uri: 'http://localhost/app/#/salesforce'

Comment: I have only done OAUTH2 on the server-side so am not clear on what a purely client-side implementation looks like. But as localhost means ["this computer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), by passing that string you are not supplying the IP address of your client (that it looks like your are trying to do). I suggest you Google to find examples of a purely client-side approach and if you can't post a new question on what s the best starting point to do that.

Comment: Keith C..I tried with ip address. but, It does not work. When I tried to save redirect url in developer account of salesforce, It does not allow. I will do more googoe. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you can't figure it out a good person to try to get in touch with on this is @metadaddy (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem myself.

I required to decode my code

```
params = {
    code:decodeURIComponent(authCode),
    grant_type:'authorization_code',
    client_id:'23232',
    client_secret:'weewew',
    redirect_uri: redirectURL
};
```

It works fine for me.

Thanks ! :)